# Parental Control In my App

Tags: ios4

This is my first application. I want to add parental control in my application, as it is meant to be used by them. Is this possible.

Thank You.

Comment: What exactly you want can you please elaborate ?

Comment: I want parents should be able to hide the application icon from my application. And they will not have to go to settings for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does not allows the applications to access other application information , so you can not access another application data like hiding icons.

This is apple sandbox for the security of the iphone , so that you cannot create application like that.

Until and unless the device is jail broken , for that some applications are available on cydia you can use that.

If you want you parents to hide any application, then one simple thing , just don't download any application that your parents don't like.